# Laravel eloquent result to collections

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a list of temperature that records every n minutes. I want to get the minimum id and maximum id for specific date. `$listDate` is a list of dates in array. eg.

```
public getTemperature() {
    $listDate = ['2016-12-08','2016-12-09','2016-12-10','2016-12-11'];    
    foreach($listDate as $date) {

        $getId = array();
        $getId[] = $this->selectRaw('MIN(`id`) as min, MAX(`id`) as max')
            ->where('created_at', '>=', $date. ' 00:00:00')
            ->where('created_at', '<=', $date. ' 23:59:59')
            ->get();
    }
    return $getId;
}
```

I want it to return as a collections like this

```
['min' => 1123, 'max' => 1345],
['min' => 1349, 'max' => 1567],
['min' => 1589, 'max' => 1612],
['min' => 1624, 'max' => 1655],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've just to define the array outside of the loop :

```
public getTemperature() {
    $listDate = ['2016-12-08','2016-12-09','2016-12-10','2016-12-11'];  

    $getId = []; //Define the array here

    foreach($listDate as $date) {
        $getId[] = $this->selectRaw('MIN(`id`) as min, MAX(`id`) as max')
            ->where('created_at', '>=', $date. ' 00:00:00')
            ->where('created_at', '<=', $date. ' 23:59:59')
            ->get();
    }
    return $getId;
}
```

Since as written in your OP the loop will init the array in every iteration.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you iterate though your list you are setting `$getId` to an empty array.

Try this

```
public getTemperature() {
    $listDate = ['2016-12-08','2016-12-09','2016-12-10','2016-12-11']; 
    $getId = array();   
    foreach($listDate as $date) {            
        $result = $this->selectRaw('MIN(`id`) as min, MAX(`id`) as max')
                                        ->where('created_at', '>=', $date. ' 00:00:00')
                                        ->where('created_at', '<=', $date. ' 23:59:59')
                                        ->get()->toArray();
        array_push($getId, $result);
    }
    return $getId;
}
```